# Mypy error: "Source file found twice under different module names: "registry" and "src.homework.homework_1.registry"

Tags: python, import, mypy

Mypy throws an error when I import the module. The project structure looks like this:

[image]

Im importing registry.py to actions.py with:
`from src.homework.homework_1.registry import *`

On github has this problem in CI

[image]

I tried using relative import `from ..homework_1.registry import *`, but another problem appears(can't run project with pycharm and python3 -m "file"):

[image]